# JSF correct use of jsf-api dependency

Tags: maven, jsf

Ok, I am a little confused on the differences between jsf-api implementations.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.8</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I am not sure what the differences are between these two. I thought they do the same thing and allow the javax.faces imports but now I have confused myself. Can anyone please explain these two differences? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was somes changes with the `groupId` of the Maven JSF-API dependency since the first version. For JSF 2.2 (current version as I'm writing this), you should use the following recommended dependency, if you are running in a container supporting JSF:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

If your container does not support JSF (like Tomcat), use the following dependency if you want to use Mojarra (the default JSF implementation):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Other recommmendation and information are available on the [official page of JSF](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html).